# How do I sum values across a data frame in R?

Tags: r, function, dataframe, apply

I've looked across multiple forums now trying to find an answer that works for me but no luck. I am probably over-thinking this but anything helps!

I have a data frame of vegetation percent cover across a number of sites (sites listed in columns with each species as a row). I would like to create a new column that counts the number of sites that each species was present in. For example, how many sites was the percent cover of Salix greater than 0?

Here is a small data frame to work from for now... (sites and species are the column names and row names, respectively)

```
           site1     site2      site3      site4
Salix      16.50      7.00       7.50       6.00 
Betula     17.75     19.75       0.00       5.25
Alnus       0.00      0.00       0.00       0.00
Picea       0.00      0.35       0.00       0.00
```

I would like the last column to look like this:

```
           site1     site2      site3      site4     count
Salix      16.50      7.00       7.50       6.00         4
Betula     17.75     19.75       0.00       5.25         3
Alnus       0.00      0.00       0.00       0.00         0
Picea       0.00      0.35       0.00       0.00         1
```

I have gotten my count function to work one row at a time but I am having trouble automating this for the entire data frame (much larger than the one I show here).

```
sum(df[1, ] > 0)
[1] 4

sum(df[2, ] > 0)
[1] 3
```

I tried a for loop like this:

```
#First I created an empty column
df$count <- NA

#Then I tried to populate that column
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  df$count <- sum(df[i, 1:ncol(df) - 1] > 0)

Error in df$count[i, ] <- sum(df[i, 1:ncol(df) - 1] > 0) : 
  incorrect number of subscripts on matrix
```

I also briefly tried working with the apply function:

```
df$count <- lapply(df, MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x) sum(x > 0))
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : unused argument (MARGIN = 1)
```

When I try remove the MARGIN argument, I get an error that it is confusing the columns with rows (this error is from my actual data which is 79 columns by 38 rows):

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, sites, value = list(`site1` = 15L,  : 
  replacement has 79 rows, data has 38
```

Any guidance?

Comment: Look into `rowSums`, or `apply` instead of `lapply`

Comment: Thanks, tried again with the apply function and it worked! (not sure what I was getting wrong before...)

df$count <- apply(df, MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x) sum(x > 0))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with `apply`:

```
df$count <- apply(df,1,function(x){sum(x>0)})
```

with `rowSums`:

```
df$count <- rowSums(df>0)
```

result:

```
       site1 site2 site3 site4 count
Salix  16.50  7.00   7.5  6.00     4
Betula 17.75 19.75   0.0  5.25     3
Alnus   0.00  0.00   0.0  0.00     0
Picea   0.00  0.35   0.0  0.00     1
```

data:

```
df <- read.table(text = "           site1     site2      site3      site4
Salix      16.50      7.00       7.50       6.00 
Betula     17.75     19.75       0.00       5.25
Alnus       0.00      0.00       0.00       0.00
Picea       0.00      0.35       0.00       0.00")
```